# Azure Data Factory - Lower Case Column Mappings

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to do a rules based mapping in order to change column headers to lowercase.

The photo is an example of what I tried in data flows activity select.

[image: Mappings Example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lower($$)` expression to convert all the matched columns from the source/input to lower case.

***Example:***

1. Source

[image]

2. In the `select` transformation apply the below **Rule base mapping** to get the lower case for all the column names.

Matched condition: `true()` and Column expression: `lower($$)`

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wonderful thank you!

Are you familiar of any way to do it in Copy Data activity?

I have tried using the Dynamic Content editor under the 'Additional Column' option of the 'Source' tab of copy data but the syntax seems different.

Thank You again!

Comment: In Additional column dynamic content, you cannot read existing columns. You can only use system variables, pipeline variables, parameters, and constants. You can use `$$COLUMN` in the additional column property to add a new column with lower case and assign the actual column name to it.